# linux chmod -R 777 /var/

Tags: linux, var, chmod, 777

By mistake I give via ssh with root privelege a

chmod -R 777 /var/

in stead of

chmod -R 777 var/ for a var folder inside a home directory.

Now I cannot login again via ssh. I have a resque mode availble.

What to do? Does someone this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, twice check your input while in root mode. Then, you need to restore correct permissions in your `~/.ssh` folder:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*
```

And, also, restore your permissions in /var directory as well:

```
chmod 755 /var/empty
chmod 755 /var/run
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried this commands but still have no ssh acces back...

Comment: I found the solutions

chmod 777 /var/tmp

Reboot system

Comment: Thank you very much for this solutions. 

I helps me perfect.